# My candidate elimination algorithm does not work

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement a "candidate elimination algorithm"  in Python but my code is not working.

I wrote 3 functions:

- `consistent` for checking the consistency between the hypotheses and the training examples
- `more_general` for finding the more general argument
- `more_specific` for finding the more specific argument

But my algorithm does not add or remove the hypotheses from `G` and `S`. I can not find where the problem is. Can you help me?

```
# the general hypothesis

G = [ ('?', '?', '?', '?') ]

# the specific hypothesis

S = [('0', '0', '0', '0')]

# attributes:
AV = (['short', 'far'], ['cheap', 'expensive'], ['many', 'none'], ['yes', 'no'])

# training examples:
D = [

    {'sample': ('far',   'cheap',     'many', 'no' ), 'positive': True },
    {'sample': ('short', 'expensive', 'many', 'no' ), 'positive': True },
    {'sample': ('far',   'expensive', 'none', 'yes'), 'positive': False},
    {'sample': ('short', 'cheap',     'none', 'yes'), 'positive': False},
    {'sample': ('short', 'cheap',     'many', 'yes'), 'positive': True }
]




 def consistent(hypothesis, sample):

   return all([hypothesis[i] == sample[i] or hypothesis[i] == '?' for i in 
   range(len(hypothesis))])


 def more_general(a, b):

    result = False
    if a == '0' and b != '0':
       result = True
    elif a != '?' and b == '?':
       result = True

    return result


 def more_specific(a, b):

    result = False
    if a == '?' and b != '?':
       result = True
    elif a != '0' and b == '0':
       result = True

    return result


for d in D:

    if d['positive']:
        G = [g for g in G if consistent(g, d['sample'])]
        for s in S:
            if not consistent(s, d['sample']):
                S.remove(s)

                # Adding to S all minimal generalizations of s by h:
                dd = d['sample'] 
                if s == 0:
                    h = dd[s]
                else:
                    h = '?'  


                if consistent(h, d['sample']) and any([more_general(g, h) for g in G]):
                    S.append(h)

                #Removing from S any hypothesis that is more general than     another hypothesis in S
                for s2 in S:
                    if any([more_general(s2, s3) and not s2 == s3 for s3 in S]):
                        S.remove(s2)

    else:
        S = [s for s in S if not consistent(s, d['sample'])]
        for g in G:
            if consistent(g, d['sample']):
                G.remove(g)

               # Add to G all minimal specializations h of g
                for ai in range(len(AV)):
                    if g[ai] == '?':
                        h = list(g)
                        h[ai] = AV[ai][1 - AV[ai].index(d['sample'][ai])]
                        h = tuple(h)
                        if not consistent(h, d['sample']) and any([more_specific(s, h) for s in S]):
                            G.append(h)




    print('Sample: {} {}\nG: {}\nS: {}\n'.format('+' if d['positive'] else '-', d['sample'], G, S))
```

Comment: Don't mutate the list you are iterating over

Comment: @bernard, I have a similar problem, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where your code breaks down for me:

```
        S.remove(s)

        dd = d['sample'] 
        if s == 0:
            h = dd[s]
        else:
            h = '?'  

        if consistent(h, d['sample']) and any([more_general(g, h) for g in G]):
            S.append(h)
```

`s` is a tuple but in the `if` condition, you're treating it as a scalar value when comparing to zero.  After the `if`, `h` contains a scalar but in the next `if`, the call to `consistent()` is expecting its first argument, `h` to be a tuple, not a scalar.

Comment: I see. But how can I fix that? should I put the h argument inside pranthesis? like h = (dd[s]) ?

Comment: I'm assuming that to be passed to `consistent()` and `more_general()`, `h` needs to be a tuple of four elements.  If you're setting it to '?', something's broken down in your algorithm.  I.e., no just wrapping it in parenthesis doesn't seem like a valid solution.  Rethink this section of the code. Add code comments.

Comment: thanks for your help. but can you explain me why it should have four elements? I am new to python